# How to update the Information of publisher stored in firestore, and using a flutter app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am designing a flutter app in which users can make publications based on their experience. The publications get stored in a firestore collection named "Publications". This collection contains the publication content, publisher's name, date of publishing, along with the profile picture of the publisher. All of the information in this collection will be used to create a good looking UI. Now, I have another collection named "Users" which contains users' personal info such as their DOB, email, name, and profile pic. My question now is that if my user decides they want to change their profile pic or name, I can change their name in the "Users" collection, But what should I do to make sure that when the profile pic is changed, all of the user's publications stored in the "Publication" collection have the updated picture too?

Also, the reason why I am storing the name and profile pic of publisher both in the publications collection as well as the users collection, is that I do not want my app to make 2 reads for only reading 1 publication, because each read costs 6 cents, and having 2 reads just doubles the money I have to pay for the firebase services.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that a read costs 2 cents.  With Firestore, reads costs 6 cents per 100,000 reads.  That's a small fraction of a penny per read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scheme might have optimized reads in the case that profile data does not change, but you've introduced a new cost for the situation where it **does** change.

If you've duplicated data like this across multiple documents, and you want to update all those documents, you will have to:

1. Query for all the documents that need to change
2. Iterate the results, and for each document
3. Update it to provide the new values

There is no shortcut for this.  Firestore does not provide a SQL-like "update where" type clause that updates multiple documents in one query.

Comment: you are actually right it's 6 cents per 100k and I think  misread the pricing. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Btw do you have a better method in mind I could use to optimize and cut cost from the process?

Comment: For products like Firestore whose billing is based on usage, that's something you'll need to compute from your expected user behavior.  There is never really one true way of doing things that works best for all sitautions.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot